# "if cell.value" comparing identical cells but not executing

Tags: python, excel, cell, openpyxl

I'm fairly new to openpyxl, so apologies if this is an obvious mistake, but I've asked for input from others and haven't found the source of my issue.

My goal is to:

- Read cell A1 from a .xlsx (inputsheet), and define it as "A".
- Define the cell adjacent to "A", in column 2 as "B"
- Compare "A" against all cells in column 1 of a *seperate* .xlsx (outputsheet)
- Write "B" into the cell adjacent to the one found in the step above
- Repeat the process, moving on to A2, A3 and so on.

The code I have written for this goal is as follows:

```
inputrow = 1  #row to copy from
outputrow = 1 #row to paste to

counter = 1

A = inputsheet.cell(row=inputrow,column=1).value #Write location name to A
B = inputsheet.cell(row=inputrow,column=2).value #Write application amount to B

while counter < 3: 
    
    #Iterate in OUTPUT for A
    for row in outputsheet.iter_rows():
        inputrow += 1                                             #moves onto next row from INPUT
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == A:                                   #when find cell that matches A        
                print ('Found Cell matching A')
                outputsheet.cell(row=cell.row,column=2).value = B #Paste B into column adjacent to what was found
                print('Cycle successful')
                counter += 1
            
            else: #if the locations don't match
                print('Location not found within output, moving to next row')
                counter += 1
                
output.save('thispart.xlsm') #save finished file as copy
```

Using this dataset as "inputsheet" (outputsheet was identical, simply lacking the numbers in column 2):

```
|Stanton | |100|
|Hurston | |200|
|Crusader| |300|
```

I receive this as an output (alongisde the following console info)

```
|Stanton | |100|
|Hurston | |   |
|Crusader| |   |

Found Cell matching A
Cycle successful
Found Cell matching A
Cycle successful
Location not found within output, moving to next row
```

I'm incredibly stuck, as it seems like my code is comparing two identical values and believing them to be different. Additional info is readily available if needed.
Any advice is welcomed, thanks!

Comment: In the `else` block, add a couple of print statements to print `cell.value` and `A`.  I bet the answer will become obvious.

Comment: Printing the value and comparing it with the value of A shows me that the value of "A" is not changing when the row is increased, thanks for the clarification, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: `A` is defined at the top of the program and never changes after that.  Are you expecting it to dynamically change based on the current value of `inputrow`?

Comment: Hey, I actually found an answer! Thanks for putting me on the right track. Essentially, like you said, A is being defined too early, and I had the incrementation of "inputrow" too early, when it should have been placed at the end of my IF statement. Thanks :)